# Create New Website Under New Domain

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create a second website within our Magento installation but I would like it to be under the same domain as our existing website.  The only difference should be that the new website has /fr/ added to the root domain i.e.

```
Existing website base url: mysite.com
New website base url: mysite.com/fr/

Existing website category url: mysite.com/category-1 
New website category url: mysite.com/fr/category-1

Existing website product url: mysite.com/category-1/product-1
New website category url: mysite.com/fr/category-1/product-1
```

Is this possible?  If so, how would I configure this?